# error: Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 3 found

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting this error: Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 3 found. (extra_positional_arguments_could_be_named at itemBuilder...and can not figure out what could be causing it.

the error is appearing here ->

```
itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => ProductItem(
          loadedProducts[i].id,
          loadedProducts[i].title,
          loadedProducts[i].imageUrl,
        ),
```

```
class ProductListPage extends StatelessWidget {
  ProductListPage({this.context});

  final List<Product> loadedProducts = [
    Product(
      id: 'p1',
      title: "Michael Kora",
      description: 'this is cool',
      price: 699,
      imageUrl:
          "https://n1.sdlcdn.com/imgs/c/9/8/Lambency-Brown-Solid-Casual-Blazers-SDL781227769-1-1b660.jpg",
    ),
    Product(
      id: 'p1',
      title: "Michael Kora",
      description: 'this is cool',
      price: 699,
      imageUrl:
          "https://n1.sdlcdn.com/imgs/c/9/8/Lambency-Brown-Solid-Casual-Blazers-SDL781227769-1-1b660.jpg",
    ),

  ];

  final BuildContext context;

//  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

      body: GridView.builder(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        itemCount: loadedProducts.length,
        itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => ProductItem(
          loadedProducts[i].id,
          loadedProducts[i].title,
          loadedProducts[i].imageUrl,
        ),

    );
  }
}
```

`ProductItem` is defined as follows:

```
class ProductItem extends StatelessWidget { 
  ProductItem({this.id, this.imageUrl, this.title}); 

  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String imageUrl;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridTile(
      child: Image.network(imageUrl),
    );
  } 
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the signature of the `ProductItem` constructor?

Comment: class ProductItem extends StatelessWidget {
  ProductItem({this.id, this.imageUrl, this.title});

  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String imageUrl;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridTile(
      child: Image.network(imageUrl),
    );
  }
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:**

`ProductItem` expects *named*, not *positional* arguments. Initialize it like so:

```
ProductItem(
  id: loadedProducts[i].id,
  title: loadedProducts[i].title,
  imageUrl: loadedProducts[i].imageUrl,
)
```

**Longer answer:**

The error informs us:

> Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 3 found.

Which suggests that `ProductItem` constructor did *not* expect *positional* arguments. It does not know what to do with them. Why? Let's inspect `ProductItem` class definition:

```
class ProductItem extends StatelessWidget { 
  ProductItem({this.id, this.imageUrl, this.title}); 
  ...
}
```

The parameters are enclosed in `{}`. In Dart, this means that they are optional *named* parameters. That is, if you decide to pass them in, you must pass them in like so:

```
ProductItem(id: 'id', imageUrl: 'url', title: 'title')
```

Note that each argument is preceded by its name - hence it is called a *named* parameter. In contrast, *positional* arguments are differentiated only by the position they take in a call to a constructor.

Class definition informs us that constructor of `ProductItem` should not be called with *positional* arguments. Instead, *named* arguments should be used. `ProductItem` should be constructed this way:

```
ProductItem(
  id: loadedProducts[i].id,
  title: loadedProducts[i].title,
  imageUrl: loadedProducts[i].imageUrl,
)
```

To read more about types of parameters, refer to Dart [documentation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#optional-parameters). Alternatively, explore the differences in [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/9dcb0dd158e831500d5de23ee7698625).